# Passing SAFEARRAY of structs containing other SAFEARRAYs

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl

I have some structs defined in an .ild file that are packed into `SAFEARRAY`and passed to a C# client...

```
[uuid(/*omitted*/)]
struct Port {
    USHORT Num;
};

[uuid(/*omitted*/)]
struct Descriptor {
    BSTR Name;
    SAFEARRAY(struct Port) Ports;
};

// Inteface method
HRESULT GetDescriptors([out, retval] SAFEARRAY(struct Descriptor)* descriptor)
```

I can unpack and use the arrays sucessfully on the C++ side. The problem is when I try to call the method from C# using the following...

```
var descriptors = comObject.GetDescriptors();
```

I get an exception stating...

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Cannot marshal field 'Ports' of type
>   'ComObjectLib.Descriptor': There is no marshaling
>   support for this type.'

Here's where it gets weird. If I add a dummy instantiation of a `Descriptor` and initialize it's fields anywhere in the C# code, the marshalling works as expected.

```
var descriptor = new Descriptor();
descriptor.Ports = new Port[0];

// Works as expected.
var descriptorsFromCom = comObject.GetDescriptors();
```

What gives?

Comment: It only works in C++ because you're in process and in the same apartment (no marshaling involved), but .NET only allows Automation Compatible Data Types (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237562.aspx). So you cannot use custom structs in SAFERARRAY. In your case, you could use SAFEARRAY of VARIANTs or SAFEARRAY or Records (VT_RECORD).

Comment: @SimonMourier I get what you're saying, but I've been sucessfully passing SAFEARRAYs of UDTs for years. I can show you how if you're interested.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you need to select the type library reference in your project's References node and change the Embed Interop Types property to False.  The compiler can only embed types that it sees being used in the code.  Forcing an interop type reference like you did is not the worst workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant Where did you get that crystal ball? Because, damn, it's good. If you'll flush your comment out into an answer, I'll mark it accepted. On a side note, is there a better option than dragging around the interop .dll or forcing a reference by creating an instance of the object?

Comment: Lucky guess, feel free to use it to complete your Q+A.  I suppose you could use the ILMerge utility, that's a guess as well.